# Error dynamically adding a highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, winjs

I am trying to add a high chart dynamically. I am getting error : 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Object expected

Below is the code I am using. What Am I doing wrong ?

```
var attributelement = document.createElement("div");
            WinJS.Utilities.addClass(attributelement, "itemmain");
            attributelement.style.width = "400px";
            attributelement.style.height = "300px";

            var chartData =  {
                chart: {
                    type: 'column',
                    renderTo: attributelement
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: [
                        'Jan',
                        'Feb',
                        'Mar',
                        'Apr',
                        'May',
                        'Jun',
                        'Jul',
                        'Aug',
                        'Sep',
                        'Oct',
                        'Nov',
                        'Dec'
                    ]
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                        '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
                    footerFormat: '</table>',
                    shared: true,
                    useHTML: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        pointPadding: 0.2,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Tokyo',
                    data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

                }, {
                    name: 'New York',
                    data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

                }, {
                    name: 'London',
                    data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

                }, {
                    name: 'Berlin',
                    data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

                }]

            };


            //templateWinCtrl.render(currentItem.data, attributelement).done(function (itemRendered) {

            //});

            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartData);
```

- Girija

Comment: Try to replace static renderTo instead of dynamic.Let's see what's happened.I think the problem is there.

Comment: I will try that... But I want it to be dynamically added...

Comment: Which line causes the error ?

Comment: Following on SteveP's question, what type of control is templateWinCtrl? Is it a WinJS.Binding.Template? 
One other quick note - most WinJS controls take a WinJS.Binding.List object as their data source. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700774.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700703.aspx.

Comment: Another comment: It's not recommended to dynamically change the width or height style values of elements using JavaScript in WinJS, particularly when you're dynamically connecting a data source. CSS properties like width, height, top, left, and display force the HTML parser and layout engine to re-render and paint the HTML page, which can lead to significant perf problems.

Comment: I tried using a static element but same error. It fails on var chart = new HighCharts.Chart(chartData);

Comment: Yes, I am adding charts dynamically to a WinJS list view. I uyse a templating function that adds these rendered charts to the list view elements. My idea was to create template items (charts) and return them as HTML generated pieces.

Comment: The issue was not referencing jquery file.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was thatr the reference to jquery was not added. Once added in default page it started to work